# How can I run two generators at same time in python

Tags: python, generator

I want two generators yielding simultaneously, but any of them can be "hang" till the other one finishes.

```
def cal(tap):
        while (tap!=0):
            tap = tap-1
            yield tap
```

and I try to use the `zip()` to achieve
but I got this
as 7 and 5 for initial

```
     6 4
     5 3
     4 2
     3 1
     2 0
```

I want to achieve this:

```
     6 4
     5 3
     4 2
     3 1
     2 0
     1 0
     0 0
```

How can I do this? Do I need some support method or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

g = zip_longest(cal(7), cal(5), fillvalue=0)

list(g)
```

Output:

```
[(6, 4), (5, 3), (4, 2), (3, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
```